# Send data via UDP connection (Bridge)

Tags: python, rest, arduino, udp, arduino-yun

I've been tasked to create a proof of concept with an Arduino Mega + Yun Shield. I've started from the Bridge sample and I can read my sensors and exposed the data through REST.

But, instead of REST, I want to send packets through UDP. I know there is samples around the web about UDP but I've have found nothing that use UDP with Bridge.

Is this feasible?

**UPDATE #1**

Ok, I read somewhere that is not possible. But I read also that is possible to run a Python script to send data through UDP.

I made that script:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = ('192.168.1.100', 9050)
message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'

try:

    # Send data
    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message
    sent = sock.sendto(message, server_address)

finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

And call it from the Arduino this way:

```
Process p;
p.begin("python");
p.addParameter("/test/sendUDP.py");  
p.run();
```

The code run without errors apparently, but my UDP server receive nothing. However, it works with PuTTY.

**UPDATE #2**
It works! I changed this line:

```
p.addParameter("/root/test/sendUDP.py");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line and it works like a charm:

```
p.addParameter("/root/test/sendUDP.py");
```